# Android ProgressBar countdown

Tags: android, progress-bar, countdown

I'm making a quiz for Android and I want a limited time to answer every question. So I want to display a ProgressBar under the answers that counts down from, for example, 5 to 0 (seconds). And when it reaches zero I want to do some stuff. I have the quiz and everything working, I just want to add the ProgressBar.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 63, accepted):

you can use countdown timer in android .

Here is one Example you can Refer [Click Here](http://gettingintomobile.blogspot.com/2011/06/android-countdown-timer-and-progress.html)

you can use below ProgressBar in your Activity.

```
   <ProgressBar 
    android:id="@+id/progressbar"
    style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
    android:max="100"
    android:progress="0"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/bottom_header_relativelayout"
    />
```

Use `CountDownTimer` Like Below code in your Activity.

```
ProgressBar mProgressBar;
CountDownTimer mCountDownTimer;
int i=0;

mProgressBar=(ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressbar);
mProgressBar.setProgress(i);
   mCountDownTimer=new CountDownTimer(5000,1000) {

        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            Log.v("Log_tag", "Tick of Progress"+ i+ millisUntilFinished);
            i++;
            mProgressBar.setProgress((int)i*100/(5000/1000));

        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
        //Do what you want 
            i++;
            mProgressBar.setProgress(100);
        }
    };
    mCountDownTimer.start();
```

Comment: Does that work with a ProgressBar? Because that's how i want to display it.

Comment: Do you want to Display it on xml layout ,i mean that you don't want pop up with Progress Right.

Comment: How do I make it tick smoother? Because now it takes 5 big steps.

Comment: Tick smoother mean , progress show step by step increment.do you get problem in Progress update,let me known which code you have use.

Comment: Solved it, forgot to change android:max in the layout.

Comment: @Herry how can we count up and show progress for one second?

Comment: @hasnain_ahmad For Showing progress for 1 Sec you need to change in new CountDownTimer(1000,10) which will call by every 10 millisecond .

Comment: @Herry what will be the value of `millisInFuture` and `countDownInterval` to delay for 2 seconds from 0 - 2 seconds not 2 - 0, means count up. what will be value should put in the `setProgress(float progress)`?

Comment: How can I stop the countdown when the user clicks for example on a button to get to the next activity? I tried to use "GONE" but its still somehow counting

Comment: @Herry Could you explain this `(int)i*100/(5000/1000)`. Trying to apply your solution to a progress bar that's decreasing instead of increasing.

Comment: In case anyone needs it to work decreasing instead of increasing `progressBar.setProgress((int)(((1.0 * millisUntilFinished) / duration) * 100));`

Answer (score 47):

You could use an `ObjectAnimator` to animate the progress of the `ProgressBar`:

```
ObjectAnimator animation = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(pb, "progress", 0, 100);
animation.setDuration(5000);
animation.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
animation.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animator animator) { }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animator) {
        //do something when the countdown is complete
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animator) { }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animator) { }
});
animation.start();
```

Answer (score 2):

**No need for XML declaration**

```
ProgressDialog TempDialog;
CountDownTimer CDT;
int i =5;

TempDialog = new ProgressDialog(Your_Class_Name.this);
TempDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
TempDialog.setCancelable(false);
TempDialog.setProgress(i);
TempDialog.show();

CDT = new CountDownTimer(5000, 1000)
{
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished)
    {
        TempDialog.setMessage("Please wait.." + i + " sec");
        i--;
    }

    public void onFinish()
    {
        TempDialog.dismiss();
        //Your Code ...
    }
}.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try in this example, It's countdown from 100 to 0 and display in the ProgressBar.

> ```
> val maxSecond = 60L
> val timerBar = viewForm.findViewById<ProgressBar>(R.id.pb_timer)
> timerBar.max = 100
> timerBar.progress = 100
> var distinct = 0.0f
> object : CountDownTimer(1000 * maxSecond, 1000) {
>   override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {
>     val second = (millisUntilFinished / 1000.0f).roundToInt()
>     val unit = (second.toFloat() / 100f)
>     if(distinct == 0f){
>       distinct = 100f / unit
>     }
>     val cal = unit * distinct
>     timerBar.progress = cal.toInt()
>   }
>   override fun onFinish() {
>     Log.d("check", "done!")
>   }
> }.start()
> ```