# Android Studio clickable Progressbar

Tags: java, android-progressbar, countdowntimer

How can I make a `ProgressBar`, which is clickable. That means you can type in a `ProgressBar`, than it shows a countdown for a few seconds. During this Countdown the `ProgressBar` is not clickable. After that Countdown you will get a reward (for example in a Game) and the `ProgressBar` is again clickable.

Comment: What did you tried so far?

Comment: I had tried to made a normal countdown progressbar, like in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10241633/android-progressbar-countdown but not very much more